# Accessing a user in forgot password method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm having a problem in accessing the email of the user in forgotpassword method.  How can I access the email without creating a new user in this method. I have send_new_password method in users.rb model.

```
def forgot_password
    if request.post?
      user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])
      puts user
      if user and user.send_new_password
        flash[:message]  = "A new password has been sent by email."
       # redirect_to root_path
      else
        flash[:warning]  = "Couldn't send password"
      end
    end
  end
```

Here is my forgot password page

```
<h1>Forgot Password</h1>
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to be doing

```
form_for(User.new)
```

since you won't have any object to put into `@user`

Comment: Please be more specific. When does it happen - when the form is rendered, or when you submit? Is there any error in the log? Try adding log messages to get an idea of where the error is happening.